# Create multiple list from array with jQuery Each

Tags: jquery, arrays, append, each

I have an array of elements, for an easier example, lets just use some numbers:

```
var items = new Array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10');
```

From this array, i want to create 4 unordered list, so every list has 3 items in it, like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>0</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
...
```

This is what i got so far, but i'm stuck here, i don't know how to proceed:

```
var ul = $('<ul>',{'class':'test'});
$.each(items,function(index,value){
    if(index%3) {
        //...
    }
    var li = $('<li>').append(value);
    ul.append(li);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AzmZq/

Comment: if you want to create 4 unordered list, so every list has 3 items in it, the array must be of size 12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.each` is overused. I would just use a basic `for` loop nested inside a `while` loop, using `Array.shift()` to remove array items one at a time:

```
while (items.length) {
    var ul = $('<ul>', { 'class': 'test' });
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (items.length) { // so we don't append empty list items at the end
            var li = $('<li>').append(items.shift());
            ul.append(li);
        };
    };
    $('body').append(ul);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/UwDdv/

---

However, if you insist on the jQuery approach, you need to append and re-initialize the `ul` each time `index%3==0`:

```
var items = new Array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10');
var ul;
$.each(items, function (index, value) {
    if (index % 3 == 0)  {
        $('body').append(ul);
        ul = $('<ul>', {'class': 'test'});
    }
    var li = $('<li>').append(value);
    ul.append(li);
});
$('body').append(ul);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/zUyRM/

Answer (score 1):

Using `$.map`:

```
var $ul = $("<ul>").append($.map(items, function(s) { return $("<li>").text(s) });
```

The day [ES6](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features) comes to all browsers, everybody will be happier (for now, we can use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)):

```
let $ul = $("<ul>").append(items.map(item => $("<li>").text(item)));
```